# Get a decompression stream for a file in a Zip file

Tags: delphi, zip

Background: I'm processing some log files that are zipped up (I'm inserting the log details into a database).  The log files are many gigabytes in size and would be nice to be able to process a file without extracting them to disk (the zip files are only a few hundred megabytes).  I have this working for an extracted log file (using a `TStreamReader`).

What I want to do is get some sort of decompression stream for one of the files in the zip file, and use that stream to process the log file without having to extract the entire file to disk.  The decompression stream needs to support files larger than 4GB.

`TZipFile` in `system.zip` looks like it has support for this, but I've not been able to get it to work - probably because it only supports 32bit file sizes and I'm dealing with files bigger than this.  I also have abbrevia installed, but can't see anything that would allow me to do this.

I'm using Delphi XE7 for this project.  Note that I'm not want to extract a zip file to a stream (the files are many GB and there wont be enough physical memory), but get the actual decompression stream.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891881)

Comment: @nolaspeaker Thanks, however system.zip only supports files up to 4GB.  I'm currently doing this, but I'm going to run into problems with some log files that are bigger than 4GB.

Comment: This seems like a recommendation question. You are asking for a library with zip64 support as I read the question.

Comment: I found this using Google (https://github.com/ccy/delphi-zip)

Answer (score 0):

I went with using the standard TZipFile in System.Zip and checking if the internal file is bigger than 4GB - roughly

```
VAR
  zipStream       : TStream;
  LocalHeader     : TZipHeader;
  StreamSize      : Int64;
  FileName        : string;
begin
//...
  Zip := TZipFile.Create;
  Zip.Open (FileName, TZipMode.zmRead);
  Zip.Read ('somefile.xml', zipStream, LocalHeader);
  StreamSize := LocalHeader.UncompressedSize;
  if StreamSize = MAXDWORD then
    ShowMessage ('File is too large, only the first 4GB will be processed'#10'To process entire file you must extract .xml file manually');
//process zipStream...
end;
```

Not perfect, but still useful